# Suggest the best pdf generation package in node

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am working on MEAN stack development project. Now am want to generate pdf. Tell me the best way to do that.Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you wanting to generate PDF from anything in particular? I.e. from HTML to PDF? Or are you just wanting to create a PDF from scratch? If you're trying to create something from scratch, I've had good experiences with hummus. https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS/wiki/How-to-serve-dynamically-created-pdf

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i html-pdf
```

Implementation :-

```
 let fname = "labelPrint-" + Date.now() + ".pdf" (THIS WAS MY USE-CASE)
 var pdf = require("html-pdf");
 var html = some html code;

 pdf.create(html).toFile(fname, function(err, aa) {
 if (err) return res.json(err);
    ...write the success code
  });
 });
```

`aa` object contains generated pdf file details